# Entity Framework OrderBy Sum over multiple joins -> local evaluation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sum, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following objects:

[image]

I want to be able to list all companies and order by the sum of the total order value.

I've tried this:

```cs
IQueryable<Company> query = _context.Companies
    .Include(c => c.InstalledBases)
        .ThenInclude(ib=>ib.Orders);

query = query.OrderBy(company => 
    company.InstalledBases.Sum(ib => 
        ib.Orders.Sum(order => order.Value)));
```

But this code gives me the warning: "The LINQ expression Sum() could not be translated and will be evaluated locally".
I have tens of thousands of companies, installed bases and orders so the query takes a long time to finish.

I'm using Asp Core 2.0.0

Is there any way to avoid the local evaluation to speed up the query?

**Edit:**

I also use Skip and Take to limit the companies currently viewed:

```
result = result.Skip(request.Start).Take(25);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue here is that there's effectively no way to wrap this all in one query. The summing of a related entity value would require a group by clause which cannot also return the data for the companies. However, being that you're *already* joining `InstalledBases` and `Orders`, running the sum and order by in memory doesn't really cost you anything: you're already returning all the data regardless.

If it's too slow, then you're really at the point where you should be offloading this to a stored procedure instead.

Comment: I forgot to add that i also use Skip & Take after the above queries, so I'm not fetching everything at once.

Comment: Okay, well everything still mostly applies. You can't do it all in one query, and especially if you're trying to order first, and then skip/take, you should strongly consider the stored procedure route. I'm not actually even sure if this is possible via Entity Framework without materializing all the data.

Answer (score 0):

So a Company has zero or more InstalledBases, and every InstalledBase belongs to exactly one Company.

Similarly: an InstalledBase has zero or more Orders, and every Order belongs to exactly one InstalledBase.

These are true one-to-many relations. [Entity Framework One-to-many relations](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) are configured similar to the following:

```
class Company
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // every company has zero or more InstalledBases:
    public virtual ICollection<InstalledBase> InstalledBases {get; set;}
}

class InstalledBase
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every InstalledBase belongs to exactly one Company using foreign key:
    public int CompanId {get; set;}
    public virtual Company Company {get; set;}

    // every InstalledBase has zero or more Orders:
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders {get; set;}
}

class Order
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every Order belongs to exactly one InstalledBase using foreign key:
    public int InstalledBaseId{get; set;}
    public virtual InstalledBase InstalledBase {get; set;}
}
```

You want all your Companies, with all their installed bases and all their Orders. The resulting sequence of Companies should be ordered by the sum of the sum of all Orders in all InstalledBases of the Company.

One of the slower aspects of a database query is the transfer of all fetched data from the database to your process. Therefore it is wise to limit the data being transferred.

If you use Include, the complete record will be transferred. This way you would transfer a lot of data that you don't need. For instance, every Company has an Id. Every InstalledBase of this Company has a CompanyId with the same value.

So if you'd ask for a Company with 20 InstalledBases, the same value for the CompanyId would be transferred 21 times. What a waste of processing power!

Therefore, consider only transferring the data you plan to use using a Select statement. This will also help you in your sum-of-sums problem.

Add the sum-of-sums as a property to your Select. Then order the sequence and return only the requested data:

```
var result = myDbContext.Companies
    // if you don't need all companies use a Where
    .Where(company => company.City = "London")
    // use a select to fetch only the data you need:
    .Select(company => new
    {
        // Fetch only the Company data you plan to use:
        Company = new 
        {
            Id = company.Id,
            Name = company.Name,
            ...
            InstalledBases = company.InstalledBases.Select(installedBase => new
            {   // use only the properties you plan to use
                Location = installedBase.Location,
                ...
                // no need to transfer CompanyId, you've already got it:
                // CompanyId = installedBase.CompanyId,

                // fetch the Orders of the InstalledBase:
                Orders = installedBase.Orders.Select(order => new
                {   // Again, only the properties you'll use
                    ...
                })
                .ToList(),
            })
            .ToList(),
        },
        // for the ordering:
        SumOfSums = company.InstalledBases
           .Select(installedBase => installedBases.Orders.Count())
           .Sum();
    })
    .OrderBy(intermediateResult => intermediateResult.SumOfSums)
    .Select(intermediateResult => intermediateResult.Company);
```

Comment: This does not solve it. You have taken the sum of the order count and not the sum of the order sums of values.

Comment: Well then, you know what to do: sum the order values instead of the order count, and order by this sum. You've got the gist don't you?

Comment: I did that but it still evaluated locally.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var q =
        from o in _context.Set<Order>()
            join ib in _context.Set<InstalledBase>() on o.InstalledBaseID equals ib.ID
            join c in _context.Set<Company>() on ib.OwnerCompanyID equals c.ID
        let t = new
        {
            o.InstalledBaseID,
            o.Value,
            c.ID,
            c.Name
        }
        group t by new { t.ID, t.Name } into g
        select new
        {
            CompanyId = g.Key.ID,
            Name = g.Key.Name,
            CompanyTotal = g.Sum(f => f.Value)
        };

        var r = q.ToList();
```

I don't know the class relations you have, but this should work, what we are doing is generating a flat view of Company, InstalledBase and Orders with the let clause, and grouping that flat view and sum up what you need.
I did not have a chance to validate this query but I think it should work on ASP.NET, but not sure if it would work on .Net Core.

PS, If you have data sets as properties on the Context instead of context.Set() you can use the set name, like context.Orders.